# Python Regex returning a list of all occurrences of block data

Tags: python, regex

I needed some help regarding finding a block of text from a text file.
The text file is a structured one.

From the File, I want to extract blocks of data which starts with a string and Ends with a } (Curly Bracket with No White Space and \r\n)
Example -:

```
ABCD = XYZAHFJKBKFF
{
    DATAFIELD1 = "TYPE1"
    {
        VALUE = 1
        VALUE = 2
        VALUE = 3
    }

    DATAFIELD1 = "TYPE2"
    {
        VALUE = 5
        VALUE = 6
        VALUE = 7
    }
}

pattern = re.compile(r"ABCD.*}",re.DOTALL)
fafs = re.findall(pattern, data)
```

This one does give me the result, but not as a list even if I use a for loop like

```
for letters in re.findall(pattern, data):
    print(letters)
```

What i want to get is a list of All the Blocks of Data between the "ABCD" and "}".
There can be many occurrences and I want to get all of them in an iterable format or as a list.

can someone please help me with this.

Comment: It seems like you want overlapping regexes if there are multiple, since right now it will only match the first ABCD and the last } I believe.

Comment: Exactly. That's what is bothering me. The thing is i want to extract the blocks and save as separate text files. So if my txt file has 3 ABCD and 3 curly brackets meaning 3 blocks of data. It will return me 3 blocks but only as a single item and not as a list of 3

Answer (score -1):

Here, try this, it does what it sounds like you want:

```
txt = """ABCD = XYZAHFJKBKFF
{
    sdfsd
    sd
    fsd
    fsd
    fsd
    fsd
    fsd
    fsd
    (This can be anything and including most common characters)
    (This may Include Curly, Round brackets as well)
}"""

pattern = re.compile(r".*")
_fafs = re.findall(pattern, txt[txt.index("ABCD")+4:txt.rindex("}")])
fafs = [faf for faf in _fafs if faf != ""]

for letters in re.findall(pattern, txt):
    print(letters)
```

The `fafs = [faf for faf in _fafs if faf != ""]` line is to remove the empty string items that appeared. Also, if you want to strip whitespace from the chunks of data, then replace that with `fafs = [faf.strip(" \t\n\r") for faf in _fafs if faf != ""]`, and add any other whitespace characters (besides spaces, tabs, and two different newlines) into the str that is the argument to strip.

Oh, and replace txt's string literal with a call to whatever will procure the data you wish to parse. And if you want a starting flag other than "ABCD", then replace `txt.index("ABCD")+4` with `txt.index(flag)+len(flag)`

And alternatively to `_fafs = re.findall(pattern, txt[txt.index("ABCD")+4:txt.rindex("}")])`:
    ind = txt.index(flag)+len(flag)
    _fafs = re.findall(pattern, txt[ind:txt.index("}", ind)])

BUT that'll stop at the first close brace after the starting flag.